# ProviderNotFound Exception when using with Generics & Abstraction

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm facing this very weird and primitive issue, I'm trying to figure it out but not able to.

I've designed an abstract class in following manner

```
abstract class BaseStatelessWidget<T extends BaseStore> extends StatelessWidget
    with RouteAware {
  late final T childStore;

  BaseStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    childStore = getImplementedStore();
    return Provider(
      create: <T>(_) => childStore,
      builder: (ctx, __) {
        final store = Provider.of<T>(ctx, listen: false); // <== I'm getting error here for providerNotFound excepton
        store;
        return _BaseStatefulWidget<T>(
          builder: buildScreen,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context);

  T getImplementedStore();
}
```

This is the way I've implemented the Above abstract class,

```
class Counter extends BaseStatelessWidget<CounterStore> {
  Counter({super.key});

  @override
  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: AppColors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Observer(
              builder: (ctx) {
                return Text(
                  '${getStore<CounterStore>(ctx).counter} Times Clicked',
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          getStore<CounterStore>(context).increment();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  CounterStore getImplementedStore() {
    return getIt<CounterStore>();
  }
}

T getStore<T extends BaseStore>(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false);
}
```

As soon as I call the **Provider.of** method to get the injected object, I'm getting the exception.
Can someone point out, if I'm missing anything here??

Comment: Instead of using the builder parameter for exposing the child, I think you might need to place the element that accesses the provider in the *child* of the Provider. Kindly see if that is causing the issue? I think the builder param is used in the building of the provider itself.

Comment: Are you saying I should give a try by replacing builder with child?

Comment: Yes, because builder would be used to build the provider, child would be the scope in which the provider can be accessed.

Comment: I tried that way as well, but no luck

Comment: Hi firstly a correction from my side. Using builder is indeed correct,

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the provider, drop the return type in the create function:

```
    abstract class BaseStatelessWidget<T extends BaseStore> extends StatelessWidget with RouteAware {
  late final T childStore;

  BaseStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    childStore = getImplementedStore();
    return Provider(
      create: (_) => childStore,//Drop the return type
      builder: (ctx, __) {
        final store = Provider.of<T>(ctx, listen: false);
        return Text(store.value());
      },
    );
  }

  T getImplementedStore();
}
```

Tried the same and was able to get the provider's value as expected.

Comment: I tried the same way, issue was persisting, Can you tell me about the version of provider you are using?

Comment: provider: ^6.0.5

Comment: Can you add the implementation of the classes instead of adding just the base classes?

Comment: I've added it, It's not all the implementation, but it will give you an idea about the way abstract class is being used

Comment: When using getImplementedStore, have you confirmed that a non null  object is being returned?

Comment: Also I'm not very sure of what functionality getIt<CounterStore> provides? Why not look for the CounterStore type of provider directly at that point?

Comment: We can do that, its a way you architect your code, This is basically for dependency injection. And I think this is not causing the issue, I think, I've figured it out. Provider Package is not very detailed.

Comment: Lovely. Please update the thread with what was causing the issue.

Comment: updated, Thanks for your constant support. 

Answer (score 0):

After thorough research, I've found a solution that could be helpful to others encountering a similar issue.

The provider package offers two methods to create a provider:

- Using the Provider(create: (context) => TExtends())
- Utilizing Provider.value(value: TExtends()).

It's important to note that the first approach lacks abstraction support. Attempting to access **T** directly from the context will result in an exception. This is because the provided object will represent the *implementation* of **T**, rather than **T** itself.

If your objective is to obtain an instance of **T** instead of *TExtends*, I recommend opting for the second method. This will allow you to resolve the issue.

Here's an example implementation:

```
abstract class BaseStatelessWidget<T extends BaseStore> extends StatelessWidget
    with RouteAware {
  late final T childStore;

  BaseStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    childStore = getImplementedStore();
    return Provider<T>.value( // <== This will solve the issue
      value: childStore,
      builder: (ctx, __) {
        final store = Provider.of<T>(ctx, listen: false); // You'll get instance of T, instead of childStore's instance
        store;
        return _BaseStatefulWidget<T>(
          builder: buildScreen,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context);

  T getImplementedStore();
}
```